# jvmti agent fatal error on linux: C [libc.so.6+0x7ae68] strcpy+0x18

Tags: crash, strcpy, jvmti

I have written a jvmti agent to trace method invocations. I code it with C and jvmti and jni functions. Our os is Fedora 15 and the agent is compiled into a `.so` file. When I test it with a non-trivial java program, it crashes and gives the following error message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x4e8e4e28, pid=24294, tid=3065949040.
  JRE version: 6.0_32-b05.
  Java VM: Java HotSpot (TM) Server VM (20.7-b02 mixed mode linux-x86).
  **Problematic frame:
    C [libc.so.6+0x7ae68] strcpy+0x18.**
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

> [IGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) is an abbreviation for Signal Segmentation Violation. On
>   POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGSEGV is the signal sent to a process
>   when it makes an invalid memory reference, or **[segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)**.

You have to check the pointers in your JVMTI agent. In all probability you make some unclean pointer operations.